# FileZilla Misreports File Sizes

Tags: windows-server-2003, filezilla, winscp

I have the task of downloading some backups from our hosted web site and the backup are quite large, 4,755,281KB, yes it's over 4GB.  I installed FileZilla and navigated to the remote directory and it reports the file as 574,440,070.  I'm guessing that is 574MB.

Is this a known issue with FileZilla?  I did some Googling and I can't find a solution.

Edit:
I just tried WinSCP and it reports the file as the same size, this is getting weirder

Edit 2:
I just checked the FTP Server and it's set to "220 Serv-U FTP-Server v2.5n for WinSock ready..."

Edit 3:
Apparently the Serv-U daemon installed doesn't support files above 4GB properly.  I was able to combine the files into one backup and then I was able to download the files without corruption

Comment: Do you have ssh or rdp access to the server so you can check the filesize on the machine itself?

Comment: @MrStatic, yes, I got the file sizes from Windows Explorer

Answer (score 0):

It certainly won't be an issue with Filezilla which from your edits I assume you've ascertained. More than likely it's due to the file system employed or a constraint placed by your hosting provider, I'd confirm both with them.

Alternatively have you considered compressing and splitting the file into say 500mb chunks and downloading those? I'm unsure what tools you have at your disposal to do this if you don't have SSH access but I'd imagine that whatever you're using to create these backups would have provisions for splitting the backup into manageable files and failing that that your hosting provider would have some kind of system in place for helping users extract large files.